# Creating a table in the database for each hardcoded type or creating a single SystemType table using EF Code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have hardcoded types defined in the business logic for my application. For example for my Product entity the hardcoded types are: Missing and Available.

Should I be creating a Model called ProductType {Id, Name} or creating a Model called SystemTypes {Id, Name, Value, FriendlyName, SortOrder, etc...} that will handle all static types that will only be updated/managed by the developer not the user.

Comment: It is up to you. But it is a good practice to keep those in a table because what if tomorrow there is a new type you want to add to the system ? Would you prefer to simply add a record to the system or go and update your code, recompile ,re-test and re-deploy ?

Comment: @Shyju Good point! One last question: When should I think Enum versus storing these types in the database? I would say Enum when they will not be needed to populate a dropdownlist and database if they need to populate a dropdown list. Because in order to populate a dropdownlist with Text/Value (with text being a friendly name with spaces) pairs looping through an Enum won't work I believe.

Comment: Things which are always a non changing set. For example, **Live** or **Alive**

Comment: @Shyju Yes, but lets say I need to populate a DropDownList based off of them? How can this be done... What if I need spaces in the Friendly names. Is database my only option at this point? I updated my previous comment above.

Comment: There are lot of samples in many SO posts. Just search for "populate dropdown from enum in mvc". If you need more control, go for a db table.

Comment: @Shyju I am aware of this and I know how to populate a DropDown from an Enum, but the issue comes in in the following case: A DropDown has a DataText and a DataValue field. An Enum does not satisfy the DataText field when there are spaces needed. For example 'Is Alive' and 'Is Live' Do you get what I am saying now?

Comment: Then go for a table.

Comment: @Shyju Alright thanks for helping me think through this!